# ML syntax highlighting and type variables

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

If you look at the following questions tagged sml, ocaml and F# respectively, you'll see that the formatting is broken:

- [unfolding lists in ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469012/unfolding-lists-in-ml)
- [type of higher order functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443351/type-of-high-order-functions)
- [Map Reduce with F# agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431743/map-reduce-with-f-agents)

It seems the problem is that `'foo` is interpreted as the start of a string, not as a type variable as it should be.

At first I thought that the question were not correctly interpreted as ml-questions, but looking at the source code shows me that the `<code>` tags do indeed have class `lang-ml prettyprint`.

So I looked around at the prettify homepage and found [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=130&can=1&q=ml), which seems to describe the same problem. It is marked as fixed.

Since the bug is still happening on SO, I suspect SO might be using an old version of lang-ml.js (or the bug isn't really fixed - but it looks fixed in the source), so I suggest upgrading to the [current version](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-ml.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pulled the latest code from the google prettify repository - it will go out tonight.